# Ajax not getting data on some machines

Tags: java, ajax, angularjs

I have a web project in which i am using ajax post request to get data and it works fine on some machines on firefox as well as google chrome browser.

But not on some machines there are no errors in server as well as browser logs. Can someone guide me how to resolve this issue.

Here is my angular js ajax request

```
app.controller('HttpController', function($scope, $http){
     $scope.get = function() {
            var user =  $('#user').val();
            var actionUrl = '/admin/getClients'
debugger;   
            $http({
                method : 'POST',

                url : actionUrl,
data: {  

                    user : user
                },

            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.systemUsers = data;

                $("#selectreport").show();
                $("#userdiv").show();
                $("#userlable").show();
                $("#gobutton").show();


            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                debugger;
                $('#LoadingImageDiv').hide();
            });
     }
```

I am getting data on some machines and not on others on live server.While i can see data while returning from java

Here is my backend code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getClients", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ArrayList<JSON_SystemUser> getClients(
            @RequestParam("user") String user, Principal principal) {
        ArrayList<JSON_SystemUser> systemUsers = null;

        if(principal!=null){
            SystemUser systemUser = logincontrollerserviceint

                .getUserByUsername(principal.getName());
        if (systemUser.getClientRole().equals("User")) {

            SystemUser masterUser = logincontrollerserviceint
                    .getUserByUserId(systemUser.getUsermasterId());
            systemUsers = adminServiceInterface
                    .getUserByAdminClientnameAndClientref(
                            String.valueOf(masterUser.getId()),
                            user.split("-")[0], user.split("-")[1]);

        } else {
            systemUsers = adminServiceInterface
                    .getUserByAdminClientnameAndClientref(
                            String.valueOf(systemUser.getId()),
                            user.split("-")[0], user.split("-")[1]);

        }
    }
        return systemUsers;

    }
```

Comment: Not a Java person, but could it be a user issue and not a machine issue, as in the user not being authenticated/authorized?

Comment: But i am testing for same credentials from two different locations and it gives this problem @glennanthonyb

Comment: Sorry @kirti, did you mean same credentials from two different machines, and it works on one machine, but not another?  Any 4xx/5xx HTTP status codes returned?

Comment: Yes same username password and it does works on some but not on few machines.It's not giving any http error code returned it gives 200 status

Comment: Any body data in the response?

Comment: @glennanthonyb it gives " " in data response for that machine on which its not working

Comment: Are you able to debug the server, or, if `systemUsers` is null, to return an alternative HTTP status code?

Answer (score -1):

do you have logs on the server side? and if yes then do they roll as the request is sent from the server? If yes, then it means the request does reach the server, however it fails to reach back to the client.

In chrome you can try with developer toolbar in which you get to know what happend to the request. Like the server has timedout/ no response was received/ was there an error code returned by the server.

To start with mmake sure your server and the client m/c are both on the same lan.